# Get the Header Value In wcfWebapi Using Handler

Tags: wcf-web-api

How can i get the Header value in the WcfwebApi using the Handler before entering the Web-method .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an OperationHandler<RequestMessage, RequestMessage>

It gets passed a RequestMessage in which you can access the the headers:

```
public class HeaderAccessRequestHandler : HttpOperationHandler<HttpRequestMessage, HttpRequestMessage> {

    public HeaderAccessRequestHandler() : base("request") {
    }

    public override HttpRequestMessage OnHandle(HttpRequestMessage request) {

        request.Headers.Remove("Accept"); // remove value and 
        request.Headers.Add("Accept","text/html"); // set it new = update 

        return request;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want get the Header variable and Change the value before entering the Web methods Can u give me Sample little bit of code ?